# in Dart, problems with static method when called from variable

Tags: class, static, dart, dart-mirrors

have class `Klass` with static method `fn1`

```dart
class Klass {
  static String fn1() => 'hello';
}

> Klass.fn1(); //  hello
```

but when `Klass` is assigned to a variable, calling the method `fn1` fails

```dart
var k = Klass;

> k.fn1() // "Unhandled exception: Class '_Type' has no instance method 'fn1'.
```

don't quite know what's going on here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple workaround

```dart
class Klass {
  static fn1(String name) {
    return name;
  }
  
  fn1NonStatic(String name) {
    return fn1(name);
  }
}

Klass().fn1NonStatic("test");
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the intent of the code here is, but you might want to use `dart:mirrors` to reflectively call `fn1()`. I don't believe you can invoke it by assigning `Klass` to a variable.  Here is how you can do it:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Klass {
  static String fn1() => 'hello';
}

main() {
  final mirror = reflectClass(Klass);
  print(mirror.invoke(#fn1, []).reflectee); // Prints 'hello'.

}
```

Comment: ok - will play with your suggestion.  but still do not know why `Klass` and `k` are different - with everything else in Dart they are the same.

Comment: I think I'm getting it.  `Klass` is a compile-time entity.  to use that entity in its run-time form requires `mirror`.